# How to gives players a deck of cards?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I'm trying to build a multiplayer card game using node.js and socket.io, and i create a deck with 52 cards and i need to give each player 13 cards, the problem is that the programme gives everybody the same first 13 cards 
players.js

```
var Player = function () {
    this.data = {
        id: null,
        name: null,
        hand:[]
    };

    this.fill = function (info) {
        for(var prop in this.data) { 
            if(this.data[prop] !== 'undefined') {
                this.data[prop] = info[prop]; 
            }
        }
    };

    this.getInformation = function () {
        return this.data;
    };
};
module.exports = function (info) {
    var instance = new Player();

    instance.fill(info);

    return instance;
};
```

card.js

```
var Card = function() {

  this.data = {
      suits : ["H", "C", "S", "D"],
      pack : []
  };

  this.createPack = function(){

    this.data.pack = [];
    this.count = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        for(j = 1; j <14; j++){

            this.data.pack[this.count++] = j + this.data.suits[i];
        }   
    }
    return this.data.pack;
  };

  this.draw = function(pack, amount, hand, initial) {  
    var cards = new Array();
    cards = pack.slice(0, amount);
    pack.splice(0, amount);

    if (!initial) {
      hand.push.apply(hand, cards);
    }
     return cards;
  };
}
  module.exports = function () {

    var instance = new Card();
    return instance;
};
```

server.js

```
var nicknames=[];

io.on("connection", function (socket) {  

var crd = card();

  socket.on('new user', function(data, callback){
        if (nicknames.indexOf(data) != -1){
            callback(false);
        } else{
            callback(true);
            socket.user = data;
            nicknames.push(socket.user);
            updateNicknames();

           var aa = { 
               id: nicknames.indexOf(data), 
               name: socket.user,
               hand: crd.draw(crd.createPack(), 13, '', true)
             };

        var pl = player(aa);

       console.log(pl.getInformation());
        }
    });
  function updateNicknames(){
    io.sockets.emit('usernames', nicknames);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, every time a user connects, you create a new deck (i.e. a complete deck), and then dealing the first 13 cards. You need to create one deck, probably when a game is created, and then draw from that (randomly, if you're into that sort of thing) - when you draw a card, you remove it from the deck.

server.js

```
var deck = crd.createDeck();

socket.on('new user', function(...) {
    player.hand = // draw randomly from deck and remove
```

Comment: still a same probleme.